# Why Expo can not load the project in react-native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to create my first `react-native` app. 
I installed `expo XDE` then I create a new project in this way :

```
create-react-native-app  firstProj
```

Then I open it in `expo XDE`  and in  terminal by `exp firstProj`

[image: Starting expo error]

But I get this warning ; And this is what is displayed in the emulator :

[image: error in emulator]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the setting button in the left top, then change the "Host" to "LAN"
2. Restart your project

Comment: where can  i set this ? in the emulator do u mean ?

Comment: in the Expo XDE, at the left top of XDE

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to create a new expo app from command line:

```
 create-react-native-app my-app
 cd my-app/
 npm start
 npm run ios / npm run android
```

In a alternate way you can try Expo XDE interface to create a app and run in your device. Here is a [official document](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v18.0.0/introduction/xde-tour.html) for creating and sharing your app across your device. If you are interested with their `CLI` you can follow the below steps

```
npm install exp --global
exp init your-project-name
cd your-project-name
exp start
```

Please check whether you have missed any of the steps from the above, it might help you to fix the issue. You might have missed `exp start` command.

Comment: when using 'exp init your-project-name' , shall i use the same  project name as my react native project ?

Comment: Yes. In the place of `your-project-name` you have to give your `react-native` project name.

Answer (score 0):

It helped the following in my case:

1. Install Genymotion with VirtualBox
2. SignUp at Genymotion site
3. Run Genymotion software and !!!SignIn
4. Close npm prompt program with project and start it again
5. npm start (in the npm promt window in the project directory)
6. Close and start Expo app, scan barcode

I noted that when my application runs successfully IpV addresses are identical

```
exp://10.0.0.124:19000   and
ipconfig -> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.124
```

Answer (score 0):

In My Case, I did this.
by Using Expo.

1. Just make sure the laptop and mobile connection with the same network.
2. Make sure that you are selected Lan on the expo web tab.
3. Stop the npm Server Running.
4. Close the App on Mobile Also.
5. Then Start npm Again.
6. Now Scan the QR Code if the project is not listed up in the expo recent open project app already.
7. Or click on the already available in recent opens project on the expo.

> Note if Still not working then try same after clearing the recent open in expo app.

I knew that this answer is too late but May it help someone.